# How to add custom attachment validation into form?

Tags: php, rsform

I have a form that using RSForm Pro to build and I have an issue where the default validation for the attachment only appear after I click submit. And the problem now is my form is using the Joomla switcher function.

Tab A | Tab B | Tab C |

Whenever I tried to submit form at Tab B or Tab C, it will return to Tab A(after click submit the page reload) and the problem is we only allow user to attach file for file format .pdf .doc .docx and attachment is not compulsory(user can choose either to upload or not)

I found out that is it possible to add custom validation to RSForm Pro(cusomvalidaiton.php) but we do not know what is the exact field name for attachment field. So my question is:

1. I believe that there is possibilities to add custom validation to our form, has anyone tried it before? Is it possible for the validation to appear and stay at Tab B without switching to Tab A after submit?
2. If custom validation is possible, may I know where can I find the source file or source name for the attachment field?